# How can I install a later version of solr-jetty via apt-get?

Tags: apt, solr

Using apt-get to install solr-jetty only gives me version 1.4 of Solr, but I would like to use one of the 3.x versions.

I'm not yet confident enough to do a manual installation (something usually goes wrong or I end up irreversibly breaking something).

Is there a way I can easily install the version of solr-jetty for I want for my version of Ubuntu via apt-get?

As an update to the question, I have tried the PPA in the suggested question, however, it did not work. I am told that this is because it is for a different version of Ubuntu.

This is the error I receive at the end of running *apt-get update*:

> Fetched 2,535 kB in 7s (354 kB/s) W: Failed to fetch
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/gasol-wu/oneiric/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources
>   404  Not Found
>
> W: Failed to fetch
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/gasol-wu/oneiric/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages
>   404  Not Found
>
> W: Failed to fetch
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/gasol-wu/oneiric/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages
>   404  Not Found
>
> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
>   ones used instead.

I have also tried an installation of Jetty and Openjdk using apt-get, but this resulted in Jetty not starting as a service.

Comment: Hi Lucio - I've updated the question to clarify the issue with the PPA.

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~webops/+archive/solr-3.5/+packages maybe if someone wants to try

Comment: Can you give the exact errors you get when you try to use the PPA?

Comment: Hi Seth - sorry, I have only just seen your message re errors. I have updated the question to include the details of the errors I'm seeing. I'm afraid I can only take them at face value - my assumption was that the files weren't there, but as I mentioned earlier, I was told that they are intended for a different version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the ppa is set only to offer oneiric packages.

> ppa:gasol-wu/**oneiric**

I have some reserves about why the maintainer did this, instead creating a sole ppa for all ubuntu versions, but ok, to solve your problem you should follow the same steps but changing oneiric for [precise](https://launchpad.net/~gasol-wu/+archive/precise):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gasol-wu/precise
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install solr-jetty
```

Of course you should purge and delete the old ppa so you won't get more errors.